# How to save UIView content (screenshot) without reducing it's quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` and I want to save it's content to an image, I successfully did that using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` but the problem is that the image quality is reduced. Is there a way to take a screenshot/save `UIView` content to an image without reducing it's quality?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.myView.frame.size);
[self.myview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: In what way is the quality reduced?

Comment: I have a `UImageView` containing an image as a subview of the `UIView`, when I save it the quality of the image is reduced.

Comment: There are many measures of quality, but I inferred the problem is downsampling: see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mital Solanki’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24649645/2207249) is a fine solution, but the root of the problem is that your view is on a retina screen (so has a scale factor of 2) and you are creating a graphics context with a scale factor of 1. The [documentation for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext) states:

> This function is equivalent to calling the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function with the opaque parameter set to NO and a scale factor of `1.0`.

Instead use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` with a scale of `0`, which is equivalent to passing a scale of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`.

Answer (score 4):

Try Following Code :

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(YourView.bounds.size, NO, 0);

[YourView drawViewHierarchyInRect:YourView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This code working Awsome...!!!